# Running time question

Tags: time

I have an array A of n integers, sorted from min to max, and two numbers a<=b, which are known to be in A. I would like to write a pseudo-code for a procedure whose running time is c1+c2log(n) and which returns the number of elements in A which satisfy a<=A[i]<=b.

I wrote the following but am not sure it satisfies the requirement for the running time and would appreciate some help:

*NB <- denotes an arrow*

```
LBound(Input: integer n, sorted array of integers A, integer a) {
  min  ← 1
  max  ← n
  while (min <= max) {
mid  ←  |_(min + max) / 2_|
    if (A[mid] < a)
      min  ←  mid + 1
else
      max  ←  mid - 1
  }
  output(min)
}
LBound(Input: integer n, sorted array of integers A, integer a) {
  min  ← 1
  max  ← n
  while (min <= max) {
mid  ←  |_(min + max) / 2_|
    if (A[mid] > b)
      max  ←  mid - 1
else
      min  ←  mid + 1
  }
  output(max)
}
Range(Input: integer n, sorted array of integers A) { 
output (1 + UBound(n,A,b) – LBound(n,A,a)) 
}
```

Comment: Did you even **look** at the preview before posting? Please do before you post - what you originally posted was unreadable.

Comment: @Oded Of course I looked at the preview! I have been trying to reformat it to not much avail for the past five minutes.

Comment: Fair enough - perhaps you should read the [formatting help](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/editing-help)?

Comment: Your worst case execution time is O(n) (if a == A[0] && b == A[n]), so no, your algorithm doesn't meet the requirement of O(log n).

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Did you not forget to take under consideration the running time of BinarySearch, also included in my code?

Comment: @Oded And I have read the formatting help. I indented the code blocks as instructed yet for some reason it failed to work.

Comment: @peripatein: No, I didn't. In big-O notation (which I used), only the dominant term is given. With lesser terms included, your algorithm has a running time comparable with `c1 + c2*log(n) + c3*n`

Comment: Code blocks need an empty line before them. Look at my edits to see what I have done.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Alright, please see edits. Is it better now? However, suppose there are duplicates in A, i.e. certain values recur. How may I handle that? I wouldn't wish to change my array (namely, shifting contents). I therefore see no way I could achieve counting the elements without using a loop. How do you reckon?

Comment: Now your algorithm has the right time complexity. The only duplicates that might pose a problem are duplications of a or b, because it is unpredictable which of those will be selected by the binary search. That is not solvable without a loop to my knowledge.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Wouldn't using a loop to find the index of the first duplicate entail exceeding the running time restrictions? In other words, I am not sure how to accomplish that under these restrictions.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I have edited my code to handle the case of duplicate values. Does it seem okay (I have tried it on several arrays but wish to make sure)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the approach you have selected will satisfy the requirement. Each binary search is O(log n), so two of them are still O(log n).

No, you haven't got the code right yet. You've got an off-by-one error in the first block and mangled formatting in the second block. As you're using 1-based subscripting there is probably another off-by-one error in your binary search but until you get the formatting right it's too hard to work out.

Actually, I haven't written a binary search in years. Isn't that what the C/C++ libraries are for?

Comment: I have edited my code to handle the case of duplicate values. Does it seem okay (I have tried it on several arrays but wish to make sure)?

Comment: You fixed one of the off-by-one errors; your pseudo-code still has formatting problems; you don't need two functions, one binary search is enough; and if you tried it you must have written real code, so why not show us what you really wrote?

Comment: I didn't write any real code. Am not trying to conceal anything. I have tried it on a piece of paper, using a few sample arrays. It did yield the desired reasults in all cases.

Comment: @peripatein: OK, then all I can say is that code doesn't look right. Check this link for one that looks much better to me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm (iterative solution)